# Incremental compile errors after java class modifications

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a relatively large PlayFramework application that is causing be headaches. Basically, every so often, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\source\target\scala-2.10\classes.bak\sbt81130890495
478.class (Access is denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileOutputChannel$1.apply(Using.scala:75)
        at sbt.Using$$anonfun$fileOutputChannel$1.apply(Using.scala:75)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.openImpl(Using.scala:65)
        at sbt.OpenFile$class.open(Using.scala:43)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
        at sbt.Using$$anon$2.open(Using.scala:64)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:23)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$copyFile$3.apply(IO.scala:586)
        at sbt.IO$$anonfun$copyFile$3.apply(IO.scala:585)
        at sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:24)
        at sbt.IO$.copyFile(IO.scala:585)
        at sbt.IO$.move(IO.scala:786)
        at sbt.inc.ClassfileManager$$anonfun$transactional$1$$anon$2.sbt$inc$ClassfileManager$$anonfun$$anon$$move(ClassfileManager.scala:75)
        at sbt.inc.ClassfileManager$$anonfun$transactional$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$delete$3.apply(ClassfileManager.scala:52)
        at sbt.inc.ClassfileManager$$anonfun$transactional$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$delete$3.apply(ClassfileManager.scala:51)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:153)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
        at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:306)
        at sbt.inc.ClassfileManager$$anonfun$transactional$1$$anon$2.delete(ClassfileManager.scala:51)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.prune(Incremental.scala:82)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:28)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:62)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:61)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:89)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:61)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:54)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.compileInternal(IncrementalCompiler.scala:160)
        at sbt.compiler.IC$.incrementalCompile(IncrementalCompiler.scala:138)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:128)
        at sbt.Compiler$.compile(Compiler.scala:114)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:814)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:805)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:803)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:235)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:226)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (PLCM/compile:compileIncremental) java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\source\ta
\scala-2.10\classes.bak\sbt811308904953346478.class (Access is denied)
[error] Total time: 18 s, completed 28-Apr-2015 5:26:55 PM
```

Once this error occurs, it will constantly occur every time I try to compile. I have to do a clean compile and that takes 25 minutes on my computer.

I've tried googling but I can't m haven't had any luck.
I think it occurs if I am modifying the source while it is running but given that is one of the supposed benefits of play... well, that would suck.

I am running windows 7 with play 2.3.8.

Comment: Try `activator clean` and then `activator compile` (sorry just blind shot)

Comment: do you sbt/activator shells open at the same time? Also seems duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631287/weird-spurious-errors-during-compilation-of-play-activator-program

Comment: Ah yes, it does seem to be a duplicate. It looks like it's not a trivial solution anyways. Thanks!